# Codeigniter site_url Function Not Working Properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm using `site_url` function on my project but there is something weird. It gets my Ipv6.

For example, I'm echoing `site_url()` and this is what I get:

http://fe40::8a43:dfff:feb3:ecff/project/

Actually I did not try anything to solve it 'cause I couldn't find anything about this problem on web. I can't use `base_url`, I have to use `site_url`. Please don't suggest things like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is most probably your ipv6 address.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited.

Comment: Try assigning your `$config['base_url'] = '';`  to a specific address

Comment: Also, what `base_url()` returns?

Comment: It solved my problem thank you. If you can post it as an answer, I can check as true answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the comment:

Try assigning your

`$config['base_url'] = '';`

to a specific address.